# Prohibit downloading Dependencies of CocoaPod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, gcdwebserver, cocoalumberjack

When I link a CocoaPod in a Podfile that includes further Cocopods via dependencies: How can I disable the installation of these dependencies (via the Podfile)?

**Background scenario:** GCDWebserver includes optional logging with CocoaLumberjack. CocoaLumberjack is nor required and only used if present in the project. Unfortunately the GCDWebserver 3.3 and newer links to CocoaLumberjack as dependency. But I don't want to include it because I'm using another logging framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately the GCDWebserver 3.3 and newer links to CocoaLumberjack as dependency

This is not the case anymore since version 3.4.1 because it created problems like yours.